# Set random name to all entries of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, request

I've got a table with a list of contacts (about 1000)
I would like to change every name of this contacts table with a random name pick from an anonymous table (100 random names, firsnames...)

I tried this request but every contact have the same name picked up from my anonymous table :

```
UPDATE contacts, anonymes
SET contacts.nom = anonymes.nom
WHERE anonymes.id_anonyme = ROUND(RAND()*99)+1;
```

Do you what I could do to update every name of my contacts table with a different random name from anonymous ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's where the `ORDER BY RAND()` clause comes in.Try this:

```
UPDATE contacts
SET nom = (select nom from anonymes order by rand() limit 1)
;
```